# How to detect which library or code depends on a native library (libmupdf.so)

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, abi, mupdf

I'm trying to reduce the APK of an android app. I found that there is a native library (***libmupdf_java.so***) used causes the APK to become larger than the expected size (It added 20MB extra size to the APK please check the [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9Um6.png)). The project has a lot of dependencies (and libraries) I couldn't find which library uses ***libmupdf_java.so***.

**Solutions I tried**

- In .gradle(app) file

  ```
      exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libmupdf_java.so'
      exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libmupdf.so'
      exclude 'lib/armeabi/libmupdf.so'
  }
  ```

The app builds successfully but I didn't know if it will fail during the runtime and crash or if it's successfully built means that all things are correct and no need to worry about any failure.

- In .gradle(app) file in release section of build types

```
ndk {
   abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'
}
```

The app builds successfully but I target only the  `ARMv8-A based CPUs` instead of targeting all three architectures (`armeabi-v7a`, `arm64-v8a`, `armeabi`)

I don't know what's the best or preferred solution.

Gradle dependencies most of them are jar files. One of them may be using the ***libmupdf.so*** :
Jar files names:

- DO_AndroidSDK_v2.4.9.jar
- BixolonPrinterV234.jar
- ZSDK_ANDROID_API.jar
- commons-io-2.2.jar
- commons-net-3.0.1.jar
- commons-validator-1.4.0.jar
- httpcore-4.3.jar
- jackson-core-2.2.3.jar
- httpmime-4.3.2.jar
- jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar
- jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar
- opencsv-2.2.jar
- jackson-core-2.2.3.jar
- snmp6_1.jar

Please, help me if you could.

Comment: do you use cpp or jni codes in your project?

Comment: No, I don't use any cpp or jni codes in the project

Comment: show your imports, maybe someone will recognize which adds this dependency. looks like some PDF-handling lib

Comment: If you mean project dependencies most of them are jar files I'll add jar names to the question. thanks.